# How do I convert dns name to hostname string in C?

Tags: c, dns, hostname

I need to turn a dns name back to a hostname string, for example I have this:

---

03 77 77 77 06 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 03 63 6F 6D
And I  want to turn it back to:

---

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

```
int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int quadCount = 0;
    char asc[256];
    printf("\nhostname\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (udp_payload[i] == 0){
            count += 2;
        }
        else
            count = 0;
        if (count == 4){
            quadCount ++;
        }

        else if (quadCount == 2){
            printf(" %02X", (unsigned char)udp_payload[i]);
            //save encoded hostname to a variable
            asc[j] = udp_payload[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
```

this code grabs the question (udp_payload) and saves the encoded hostname to the asc string.

Comment: That IS already an hostname string... seen as its hexadecimal byte representation. You'll have to be a lot clearer on what you are trying to do and show us some code.

Comment: I have a server receiving dns requests, like a man in the middle, and grabbing a dnsquery.
the dns query contains a big question and im grabbing only the hexadecimal byte representation of the hostname in it. I want then to use that string "www.google.com" to do some things with

Comment: added some code and explanation

Comment: the problem is, it stays like this: wwwgooglecom
without the dots between

Comment: What are the `ETX` (end of text, ASCII `0x03`) and `ACK` (acknowledge, ASCII `0x06`) doing in the data? What is the *actual* contents of `udp_payload`? Where does it come from?

Comment: the udp_payload comes from a dnsquery program, thats sends a payload, this payload being in this case  12 34 01 00 00 01 43 26 A8 55 00 00 03 77 77 77 06 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 03 63 6F 6D 00 00 01 00 01

Comment: To me that data looks more like a DNS *query* rather than a response. You might want to read up more about the DNS query/response protocol.

Comment: it's not a response, its a query
this program is a server and it grabbed a dnsquery from another program, the payload is that query.

Comment: And what is the problem, to extract the domain being queried? Then you really need to learn the DNS protocol, what each of the bytes and bits are doing and mean. There are many resources all over the Internet about it, not to mention [the official RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).

Comment: I've extracted it, the problem is that it's wwwgooglecom and I need it to be www.google.com, basically I want to put dots between each part of the name

Comment: And that's what you need to learn the protocol for, to be able to know what each part of the message means and how to extract only the data you want in the format you want. There's no shortcut here, you must learn it yourself.

Comment: Don't reinvent things. Use a proper DNS library. You are missing at least one important point: names can be compressed in DNS packets. As said already you might want to start by reading RFC 1034 and 1035, and multiple times if you really insist on doing the parsing yourself instead of using a library. Dots are never transmitted on the wire, the format is [label length] [bytes for the label] repeated over each label until you reach 0x00 which is the root.